# How much of the range can be used when creating audio caff files?

Tags: iphone, audio

I'm creating some sounds to use on an iPhone app, using 8K samples/s, one channel, signed 16-bit linear. All done programmatically, as in C code to output RAW then using `sox` to convert to CAF.

The possible range of values is from −32768 to +32767, however if the entire range is (over)used, I've encountered clipping distortion effects on some platforms as a side effect of various resample, filter, and interpolation operations.

Do I have to worry about this in the iPhone? If so, what would be a recommended safe range for the input, to ensure a good dynamic range, but avoid clipping?    I'd follow what Apple does in its system sounds, if there were a way to get at them!

Comment: I'm a sound engineer, not a coder, so half of your question I don't actually understand... which is worrying;) but afaik, the Apple alerts are done as AAC at approx -10dB RMS. [Not really sure if that helps as I don't understand the framework you're using]

Comment: Via the formula 10log(1/x) = -10, x corresponds to 1/10th the range, so −3300 to +3300, and correcting for RMS gives −4700 to +4700 for the amplitude. Tried it out, works great. Thanks!